# Named Pipe (Buffer?) or Shared Memory Files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-memory, named-pipes

I have a question regarding named pipes or something similar in python and wether they can be made to work for my use case. I have something like the following code.

```py
fn = path/to/my/file.ext
os.mkfifo(fn)
subprocess.check_output(args=(bar -o fn).split())
foo(fn)
```

My goal is to not write the output of the subprocess bar to disc, but rather to pipe it directly into the `foo()` function. The `foo()` function sadly only takes the filename and not a descriptor/handle of any sort. Hence I need to define some sort of in memory file which can be used by both the subprocess and `foo()` function. As I understand a named pipe is very close to what I want here, however it is designed to only work while both ends are connected and not as some intermediate in memory file/buffer, therefore it hangs already at the subprocess call (there is possibility I'm doing/understanding something wrong though). Is a named pipe the correct approach or should I use something else?

(Additionally I would also like to avoid things like `os.O_NONBLOCK` because they only work on Linux)

The `foo()` function only reads from the file.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Does [Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) and the data types it supports (such as `list`, `dict`, ...) solve your problem?

Comment: @AlirezaRoshanzamir Unless I'm misunderstanding what you are suggesting, I think sadly not because the subprocess call needs to write to an actual file on the OS, because its a completely separate program that I can't just pass a python data type to.

Comment: if `foo` only takes a filename then it seems like you have no choice but to write a file from the subprocess

Comment: @Anentropic Would it be possible if it took a file handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named pipes are a valid approach for this issue. Your current approach fails because `subprocess.check_output` waits for the process to terminate. This cannot happen until you drain the pipe. Therefore the first fix would be to call `subprocess.Popen` and let the process live while you read from the pipe.

However, that come with a new issue: How does `fn` know that the process is done? Normally you read until end-of-file (EOF). A pipe signals EOF when the writing side is closed. For a named pipe, the file entry in the filesystem is one writer (the subprocess opening the pipe counts as a second writer). So `fn` would wait indefinitely for an EOF.

What you need to do is delete the named pipe once the process is done. The easiest way to do this is with a separate thread.

```py
import os
from os import path
import subprocess
import tempfile
import threading


def call_bar(fifo_name):
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(args=("bar", "-o", fifo_name))
    finally:
        os.remove(fifo_name)


# Python doesn't have a function for safe creation of temporary named
# fifos. So we resort to a temporary directory
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    fifo_name = path.join(tmpdir.name, "fifo")
    os.mkfifo(fifo_name)
    with threading.Thread(target=call_bar, args=(fifo_name,)):
        foo(fifo_name)
```

There is one issue with this: If the process terminates before `fn` opens the pipe, the second thread may delete the pipe before `fn` gets a chance to open it. I guess this could happen if the subprocess creates no output. That exception should be easy enough to catch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation, that's exactly what I've been looking for!